# Group items with same key recursively

Tags: haskell

Given two list of the form:

```
l1 = [k1, k2, k3] 
l2 = [(k1, x1), (k2, x2), (k1, x3), (k2, x4), (k5, x5), ..)
```

I would like to group the x'es in a list with their respective key such that:

```
l = [(k1, [x1, x3]), (k2, [x2, x4]), (k5, [x5]), ..]
```

I have already googled the question and all the solutions use library code, I was however wondering how you implement this recursively. What I have so far is:

```
groupHelper [] l2 = []
groupHelper (k, value):tail1 (k1, values):tail2 | k == k1 = groupHelper tail1 (k1,(value:values)):tail2
                                                | k /= k1 = (k1, values):groupHelper (k,value):tail1 tail2
groupHelper (k, value):tail1 [] = (k, value):groupHelper tail1 (k,value)
```

As you will notice my code makes absolutely no sense. I have been stuck on this problem for some time now, so I was wondering if adding a third accumulator parameter in case I've enumerated through l1 I can go back, would help.

I'm really confused right now, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why you need `l1`.

Comment: @chepner true I didn't even realize that, l1 is indeed unnecessary. But I don't see how that would help me obtain my solution however.

Comment: On a syntactic note, you need to parenthesize a pattern that matches an non-empty list: `groupHelper ((k, value):tail1) ((k1, values):tail2) = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a simpler function: `update :: (a, b) -> [(a, [b])] -> [(a, [b])]`, which takes a single pair and updates the in-progress grouping.

```
update (k, v) [] = ...
update (k, v) ((k1, vs):rest) = ...
```

Once you do that, it' s simple matter of *folding* your list of pairs using `update`.

```
groupby :: [(a, b)] -> [(a, [b])]
groupby = foldr update []
```

If you don't want to use `foldr`, it would be a good exercise to implement *it* from scratch.

```
foldr_ :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr_ f z [] = ...
foldr_ f z (x:xs) = ...
```

There's little to be gained by ignoring the *abstraction* provided by `foldr` and trying to implement `groupby` entirely from first principles.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ty!! Something that was confusing for me is how that foldr returns a list though.

Comment: It doesn't, necessarily. It returns whatever the fold function returns, and in this case, `update` returns a list, so `foldr`/`foldr_` will, too.

Comment: Hmm I see. One more thing, the foldr function requires three parameters: the first one the function (update in this case), the second one your "base element" and lastly your list you apply the function on. I'm a bit confused about the second and third parameter here though. I assume the third one should be empty since you start with an empty list and the second one your entire list?

Comment: You have the 2nd and 3rd parameter flipped in your mental model I think. The 2nd is the base element aka the element you'd want to return if you fold the empty list, the 3rd is the list you want to fold over.

Comment: You are correct about `foldr`. I defined `groupby` in point-free style; I could have written `groupby xs = foldr update [] xs` as well.

Comment: Intuitive, `foldr` takes a function and a base case and produces a function that turns a `[a]` into a `b`. The function and the base are what define what types `a` and `b` actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily particularly elegant, but we can pattern match on the list, and then iterate over the tail to find all values with the same key, then cons the result onto the result of running the same function recursively on the remaining elements.

```
groupByFirst [] = []
groupByFirst ((k, v):tl) = (k, v:map snd s) : groupByFirst d
  where 
    (s, d) = partition ((k ==) . fst) tl
```

```
ghci> l2 = [("k1", "x1"), ("k2", "x2"), ("k1", "x3"), ("k2", "x4"), ("k5", "x5")]
ghci> groupByFirst l2
[("k1",["x1","x3"]),("k2",["x2","x4"]),("k5",["x5"])]
```

The complexity of this is less than ideal, but it should be simple enough to understand. Effectively, evaluating this would look like:

```
groupByFirst [("k1", "x1"), ("k2", "x2"), ("k1", "x3"), ("k2", "x4"), ("k5", "x5")]
("k1", ["x1", "x3"]) : groupByFirst [("k2", "x2"), ("k2", "x4"), ("k5", "x5")]
("k1", ["x1", "x3"]) : ("k2", ["x2", "x4"]) : groupByFirst [("k5", "x5")]
("k1", ["x1", "x3"]) : ("k2", ["x2", "x4"]) : ("k5", ["x5"]) : groupByFirst []
("k1", ["x1", "x3"]) : ("k2", ["x2", "x4"]) : ("k5", ["x5"]) : []
[("k1", ["x1", "x3"]), ("k2", ["x2", "x4"]), ("k5", ["x5"])]
```